# Change domain name on existing WP site

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect, hosting

I recently had a developer populate a WPLMS site for me hosted on my HostGator account.

www.midwifecafe.co.za

I did explain at the time that I wanted the site developed my main url

www.midwifecafe.com

I would then simply setup a re-direct from the .co.za to the .com domain.

The site was developed on the .co.za url and the developer now tells me he cant manage to have the site hosted on the main .com url

He now left high and dry, he's been paid and wont help anymore.

I am unsure what to do?  Is this a problem or something I can resolve?
Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: This isn't a coding question, and is probably better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. I'd check the settings file and your host domain configuration.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that developer is a jerk. This should take him 10 minutes max to do, assuming he knows how (he probably doesn't). Sorry for your bad experience.

The ultimate answer depends on a few things, like how your site is setup, etc. However generally, one of my favorite tricks for this is a little script called Search Replace DB --https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB.

Here's what you do:

1. BACKUP EVERYTHING. Yes, EVERYTHING
2. Move your site files to the new host, where the .com version will live.
3. Move your database to the new host
4. Edit your wordpress site's wp-config.php file to use the new host database information for dbname, user, password, and server (probably localhost on Hostgator).
5. Upload the search replace db folder to the root of wordpress, then access the folder in your web browser. Follow the prompts to fill in what you want to search for (www.midwifecafe.co.za) and what you want to replace it with (www.midwifecafe.com). If you're not familiar with Github, you can download the search replace script here: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip, which you'd then upload to your server in it's own folder and unzip it
6. If you run into issues, first you have a backup (see step 1), secondly you can run through their github page for tips and help.
7. Once the search and replace for the domain name runs successfully, you'll want to do two things.. DELETE THE Search Replace FOLDER. This is super important. Leaving it there is a big-time security risk. And lastly, you'll probably need to login to WordPress admin and visit the Settings > Permalinks page to generate the proper URLs on your new host.

Hopefully that's some help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> I would then simply setup a re-direct from the .co.za to the .com
>   domain....

Doesn't work that way with WordPress. But it is straightforward to move a WordPress site from one domain to another; it involves changing the URLs in the database. That's the most critical part.

But a move may also involve moving files at your host (this depends on your hosting setup) from one folder to another; you didn't say if you are staying on the same host or moving to another host at the same time as the domain change

Read the official docs [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and take a look at [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool,](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) which it sounds like you will need.

Comment: The WPLMS Theme is working under midwifecafe.co.za and it was supposed to be under midwifecafe.com

Comment: Could I not simply create a new folder in my filemanger called midwifecafe.com and copy every file to it?                                                      Or just rename the midwifecafe.co.za folder midwifecafe.com?                    I am not a programmer and I have not got a cent left to spend on this site so I am just looking for the easiest way to solve it.

Comment: Apologies,I know its not really the right forum here but thank you for your help

Comment: Read the docs I linked; that's what you need to know. You probably have to add the new domain at HG so HG creates the correct folder, and then you can move files and use the URL change script.

Answer (score -1):

I think from your question which was not completely clear, that you want to me your wordpress website from one domain to another.

**If so you can do the below manually:**

1. Download all the files from your old domain
2. Upload the downloaded files onto your new domain
3. Export database from old domain account.
4. Go to new hosting account, create a new database with username and
   password.
5. Open up PHPMyAdmin and Import the database that you exported into
   the newly created database.
6. Open up phpmyadmin an and go to the wp_options table. Replace the
   site url and home url rows with your .com domain address.
7. Then open up SQL option in phpmyadmin and run the following:

   `UPDATE wp_posts SET guid=REPLACE(guid,'www.midwifecafe.co.za','www.midwifecafe.com'); UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content,'www.midwifecafe.co.za','www.midwifecafe.com');`
8. Now open up your wp-config.php file in ftp and edit it to suit the
   new database name, username and password. For additional measures
   you can also add the below to wp-config.php:

`define('WP_HOME','http://www.midwifecafe.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.midwifecafe.com');`

9. Check your .htaccess file and make sure there is no mention of your
   old domain.

**Now run your website and see if that fixed your issues.**

Comment: Your #7 will not find/replace URLs in the wp_options table; and if you do run raw SQL queries, you break serialized data for theme and site options; always use something like https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Comment: never had an issue personally, although I build my own themes from ground up. Probably has allot to do with it.